# XPath that selects grid cells excluding nested grids

Tags: html, xpath, web

I am constructing an XPath which selects cells in a grid, indexed by column and row. I have two types of grids in the application. One is a regular grid and another has nested grids (inside of its 's).

I want a single XPath which works for both grids.

*(Yellow cell coloring indicates XPath selection)*

**Regular Grid:**

[image]

XPath:
`//*[@id='regularGrid']//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`

HTML:

```
<div id="regularGrid">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr role="row">
                <td>Things</td>
                <td>Things</td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Nested Grid (Incorrectly selecting the nested TDs):**
[image]

XPath:
`//*[@id='gridWithNestedGrid']//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`

HTML:

```
<div id="gridWithNestedGrid">
<div class="k-grid-content">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="k-master-row ng-scope" role="row">
                <td>1390</td>
                <td>1625</td>
                <td>625</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="k-detail-row ng-scope" role="row">
                <td class="k-detail-cell">4167</td>
                <td class="k-detail-cell">486</td>
                <td class="k-detail-cell">6834</td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
I need an XPath which works for both grids that doesn't select nested grids. The problem is that the nested grid div is nested inside of a div.

The following XPath works for the nested grid:

```
//*[@id='gridWithNestedGrid']/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

[image]

But I need one that works for both.

Answer (score 1):

This merged XPath selects both:

```
//*[@id='gridWithNestedGrid' or @id='regularGrid']//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

Output for the first (`regularGrid`):

```
Things
```

Output for the second (`gridWithNestedGrid`):

```
1390
```

Is that what you expect as a result?

Comment: For the nested grid, the xpath you provided will select the nested cells. To make it not select the cells, the path needs a div: //*[@id='gridWithNestedGrid' or @id='regularGrid']/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1].  But this path will no longer work with the regular grid.

Comment: I'm sorry. I really do not understand what you mean. There must be an error in your [mcve], because my solution does fulfill both the `regular` and the `nested` grid requirements.